# Why are these mushroom stems leaving a long, skinny fiber behind on the cap?

Tags: food-safety, mushrooms

I was pulling the stems out of some mushroom caps today - we save the stems and make broth out of them - when I discovered that some stems weren't coming out all the way. Have a look:

[image: Mushrooms]

Mushroom fanatics out there: Any idea what causes this? Is there something wrong with these mushrooms? Am I being paranoid because I just read [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/3225/how-can-i-tell-if-a-mushroom-is-poisonous)?

Comment: It looks like the stems just got a little woodier in the center and held on tighter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jefromi's comment is spot on. I wouldn't be paranoid. The stem probably just didn't feel like coming out and hung on the head. This is completely normal and unless you picked these mushrooms yourself, I would never worry about that.

Answer (score 3):

Mushrooms are complicated little guys. What you see as a single type of mushrooms is actually hundreds of different substrains. Its possible they're from a slightly different batch than what you're used to, and so have slightly different stems. I wouldn't worry about it, and enjoy the mushrooms!